# Не получается применить QSplitter для разделения окна на 3 части

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qsplitter

Прошу прощения за сумбур в теме, но *PyQt5* я начал изучать совсем недавно и сложно дается концепция организации интерфейса.

Требуется организовать окно, которое представлено на следующей картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, требуется разделить окно на **3** части, размеры которых можно менять, используя `QSplitter`.

Написал код:

```
class SelectionWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # инициализация
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)  # инициализация
        # создать горизонтальный box
        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        # создать два вертикальных vbox
        self.vbox1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        # создать 2 vbox, которые будут делить vbox2
        self.vbox21 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox22 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        # добавить в горизонтальный hbox два вертикальных
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox1)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox2)
        # vbox2 делим на 2 части
        self.vbox2.addLayout(self.vbox21)
        self.vbox2.addLayout(self.vbox22)
        # создание компонентов
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label1")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label2")
        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label3")
        # установить стиль и параметры компонентов
        self.label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        # добавить компоненты
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.vbox21.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.vbox22.addWidget(self.label3)
        #
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
```

Сначала создал горизонтальный `hbox`, в который добавил **2** вертикальных - `vbox1` и `vbox2`.
В свою очередь `vbox2` разделил на **2** - `vbox21` и `vbox22`.

Есть у меня смутные сомнения, что сделал я неправильно...

Дальше процесс встал окончательно - как добавить `QStlitter`?

Единственный пример, который я нашел - демонстрировал применение `QSplitter` для разделения `QFrame`, но это не то, что мне нужно.

Может, что-то сможет мне помочь кодом или ссылкой на хороший пример. Или мой код просто некорректный?

С уважением, Роман

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        topRight = QFrame()
        topRight.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        labelTopRight = QLabel(" labelTopRight", topRight)

        leftFrame = QFrame()
        leftFrame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        labelLeft = QLabel(" labelLeft", leftFrame)

        splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)

        textedit  = QTextEdit("Hello World")
        splitter1.addWidget(topRight)
        splitter1.addWidget(textedit)
        splitter1.setSizes([100,200])

        splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)

        splitter2.addWidget(leftFrame)        
        splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)

        hbox    = QHBoxLayout(self)        
        hbox.addWidget(splitter2)
        self.setLayout(hbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)    
    ex.setWindowTitle('QSplitter demo')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вы плохо искали :)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class SubWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, label, parent=None):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(label, parent=self)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-size:40px;}")

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.sub_win_1 = SubWindow("1", parent=self)
        self.sub_win_2 = SubWindow("2", parent=self)
        self.sub_win_3 = SubWindow("3", parent=self)
        self.sub_win_4 = SubWindow("4", parent=self)

        self.sub_splitter_1 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent=self)
        self.sub_splitter_1.addWidget(self.sub_win_1)
        self.sub_splitter_1.addWidget(self.sub_win_2)

        self.sub_splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent=self)
        self.sub_splitter_2.addWidget(self.sub_win_3)
        self.sub_splitter_2.addWidget(self.sub_win_4)

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, parent=self)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.sub_splitter_1)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.sub_splitter_2)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Layout example")
        self.resize(500, 500)

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Обратите внимание на StyleSheet , в т.ч. и на QSplitter

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QSplitter, 
                             QFormLayout, QLabel, QFrame, QPushButton, 
                             QMenu, QAction)                                      
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QFont, QIcon


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.create_menu_bar()
        self.create_body()

    def create_menu_bar(self):
        self.menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        self.file_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("File")
        self.file_menu.addAction('New')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Open')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Save')
        self.file_menu.addAction('Save as')

        self.exit_menu = QAction(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/exit.png"),'&Exit', self)
        self.exit_menu.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exit_menu.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.exit_menu)         

        self.view_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("View")
        self.view_menu.addAction('set Full Screen')
        self.view_menu.addAction('show Status Bar') 

        self.edit_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("Edit")
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Cut')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Copy')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Paste')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Find')
        self.edit_menu.addAction('Replace') 

        self.help_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("Help")
        self.help_menu.addAction('Help')
        self.help_menu.addAction('About')

    def create_body(self):
        form_frame = QFrame()
        form_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        form_frame.setMinimumWidth(150)

        f_label = QLabel('Welcome')
        s_label = QLabel('Installation')
        p_push = QPushButton('Sign in')
        p_push.setContentsMargins(10, 20, 10, 10)

        form_lay = QFormLayout()
        form_lay.addRow(f_label)
        form_lay.addRow(s_label)
        form_lay.addRow(p_push)
        form_frame.setLayout(form_lay)

        ver_frame = QFrame()
        ver_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        intro_label = QLabel("Welcome to The  Open Space ")
        intro_label.setFont(QFont('Serif', 16))

        ver_box = QVBoxLayout()
        ver_box.setContentsMargins(25, 20, 25, 25)        
        ver_box.addWidget(intro_label)
        ver_frame.setLayout(ver_box)

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(form_frame)
        splitter.addWidget(ver_frame)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setCentralWidget(splitter)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        men = QMenu()
        men.addAction('New')
        men.addAction('Open')
        quit = men.addAction('Quit')
        action = men.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action is quit:
           self.close()


StyleSheet = '''
QMainWindow {
    background-color: #333;
    color: red;
}

/* QMenuBar --------------------------------------------------------------- */

QMenuBar {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,
                                      stop:0 lightgray, stop:1 darkgray);
}
QMenuBar::item {
    spacing: 3px;           
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background-color: rgb(210,105,30);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);  
    border-radius: 5px;
}
QMenuBar::item:selected {    
    background-color: rgb(244,164,96);
}
QMenuBar::item:pressed {
    background: rgb(128,0,0);
}

/* QMenu ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

QMenu {
    font: 12pt;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
QMenu::item:selected {
    color: gray;
}

/* QSplitter -------------------------------------------------------------- */

QSplitter::handle:horizontal {
    width: 2px;
    background-color : green;
}

QSplitter::handle:vertical {
    height: 2px;
    background-color : green;
}

/*  ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

QLabel {
/*    background-color : blue;*/
    color: #ccc;
}

QPushButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #777;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #999;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #bbdefb;
    color: green;
}

'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                    # <---

    win = Window()
    win.setWindowTitle('First Porgram')
    win.setWindowIcon(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png")) 
    win.setGeometry(300, 150, 500, 300)
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, спасибо.  Это, в общем, единственный пример, который есть по Splitter. Только не нравятся рамки, которые создает QFrame. То есть я не могу менять размер непосредственно QVBoxLayout(), используя QSplitter?

Comment: @РоманКоротовских  добавил следующий пример